# Haunted Houses in New York City

Tags: usa, new-york-city, seasonal

My friend is coming into town this weekend and I was hoping to take her to a ["haunted house"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haunted_attraction) (of the scary attraction kind rather than the supernatural kind) here in New York City. When we lived in Indiana, there was this amazing haunted house in the middle of a field at the end of this really creepy-as-heck country road. Given that New York has *way more* out of work actors, I'd hope there's a better selection of haunted houses in these parts.

We're willing to go as far as Connecticut, but I don't have a car, so attractions in/around Manhattan are preferred. Please try to include the admission fee and/or a link to the attraction website.

Family-friendly is fine, though my friend and I are both 21+ and not particularly prudish.

Comment: What is a haunted house? Some kind of attraction?

Comment: @gerrit Yup! It's basically a seasonal attraction that features a location (warehouse, converted home, shack, etc) that has been decked out in a "house of horrors," filled with spooky decorations, people dressed as monsters, and sometimes tricks and theatrical efforts. In some parts, these are also called a "haunted hayride," or something similar. Check out [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haunted_attraction).

Comment: @Aarthi *house in the middle of the field* that's about 99% of farm houses. :)

Comment: @Karlson Well, yeah, but this place was *the bomb* and it was only $10.

Comment: @Aarthi I was hoping you were referring to the real haunted house...

Comment: I also thought you were asking about houses that some people believe to be inhabited by ghosts.

Comment: @hippietrail There are places that are both like [Eastern State Prison](http://www.easternstate.org/)

Answer (score 8):

There are plenty of haunted houses around the City and in surrounded areas let's start with the obvious:

- [Times Scare](http://timesscarenyc.com/)
- [Nightmare NYC](http://nightmarenyc.com/)
- And of course [Jekyll & Hyde](http://www.jekyllpub.com/) series of haunted establishments.

There are also plenty of online resources that list the haunted houses as well like [HauntedHouse.com in New York](http://www.hauntedhouse.com/search/Haunted_Attraction_Directory/_USA_,040All_50_States,041/New_York/) and [New Jersey](http://www.hauntedhouse.com/search/Haunted_Attraction_Directory/_USA_,040All_50_States,041/New_Jersey/) so pick your poison. :)